# htmlfile: Access is denied

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a Telerik rad upload control that is hidden on the page.
I have another button that opens the popup of the radupload control.
After selecting a file the OnClientFileSelected event will be fired.

The problem is that I am trying to do a post back in the OnClientFileSelected, Internet Explorer is giving me the below error.

Note that this is working fine on FireFox.

Any Help is very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this help?: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/iewebdevelopment/thread/6748585f-f81c-404a-8009-4259a3515f65

Comment: That is not an Internet Explorer dialog.  That dialog is coming from the third-party plugin.